# Inconsistent number of samples in Sklearn with XGBoost

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am trying to train a `XGBRegressor` using this code:

```
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

def xgboost(): 
    model = xgb.XGBRegressor(n_estimators=200,
                             max_depth=4,
                             subsample=1,
                             min_child_weight=1,
                             objective='reg:squarederror',
                             tree_method='hist',
                             eval_metric=mean_squared_error, # mean_squared_error
                             early_stopping_rounds=50)
    return model

num_amostras = x_train.shape[0]
val_size = 0.2
num_amostras_train = int(num_amostras * (1-val_size))
x_train_xgb = x_train[:num_amostras_train]
y_train_xgb = y_train[:num_amostras_train]
x_val_xgb = x_train[num_amostras_train:]
y_val_xgb = y_train[num_amostras_train:]
model_xgb = xgboost()
model_xgb.fit(x_train_xgb, y_train_xgb, eval_set=[(x_train_xgb, y_train_xgb), (x_val_xgb, y_val_xgb)])
resultados = model_xgb.evals_result()
```

`x_train` has shape `(1458, 55)`, `x_train_xgb` has shape `(1166, 55)`, `y_train_xgb` has shape `(1166, 24)`, `x_val_xgb` has shape `(292, 55)` and `y_val_xgb` has shape `(292, 24)`.

But i am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\PeDFurnas\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\ldsp_\sipredvs\scripts\treinamento_demanda.py:201
    model_xgb.fit(x_train_xgb, y_train_xgb, eval_set=[(x_train_xgb, y_train_xgb),(x_val_xgb, y_val_xgb)])

  File ~\PeDFurnas\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py:729 in inner_f
    return func(**kwargs)

  File ~\PeDFurnas\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py:1086 in fit
    self._Booster = train(

  File ~\PeDFurnas\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py:729 in inner_f
    return func(**kwargs)

  File ~\PeDFurnas\lib\site-packages\xgboost\training.py:182 in train
    if cb_container.after_iteration(bst, i, dtrain, evals):

  File ~\PeDFurnas\lib\site-packages\xgboost\callback.py:238 in after_iteration
    score: str = model.eval_set(evals, epoch, self.metric, self._output_margin)

  File ~\PeDFurnas\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py:2138 in eval_set
    feval_ret = feval(

  File ~\PeDFurnas\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py:139 in inner
    return func.__name__, func(y_true, y_score)

  File ~\PeDFurnas\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_regression.py:442 in mean_squared_error
    y_type, y_true, y_pred, multioutput = _check_reg_targets(

  File ~\PeDFurnas\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_regression.py:100 in _check_reg_targets
    check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)

  File ~\PeDFurnas\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:397 in check_consistent_length
    raise ValueError(

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [27984, 1166]
```

So `27984 = 1166*24` (the product of `y_train_xgb` shape).

`1166` is the number of sample of both `x_train_xgb` and `y_train_xgb`

If i don't use a sklearn metric (`mean_squared_error` in this case), and i use the default metric of `XGBoostRegressor` (`'rmse'`), the code runs just fine.

So, what is the cause of this problem here? How to fix and use `mean_squared_error` as `eval_metric`?

Comment: 1) If you remove the `eval_set` argument from the `.fit` method, do you get the error?

2) Why does `y_train_xgb` have more than one colum? It's a data label, it should have only one column (e.g. (1166, 1)), shouldn't it?

3) IIUC, here you are splitting your dataset into train and test sets:
`num_amostras_train = int(num_amostras * (1-val_size))
x_train_xgb = x_train[:num_amostras_train]`

There's an easier way to do this, use `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`

Comment: @Lfppfs

1) No, i don't get the error. 2) Because my model has 24 outputs, it is not a  single label. 3) I know, but i need the last 20% of my `x_train` to be the validation set, that's the reason i split it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, custom metrics are not supported with multi-output models.

[Source](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/9730)

One can train with the custom `'rmse'`, and if only the `'mse'` information is needed, you can obtain it by:

```
mse = rmse**2
```